# Where am I supposed to catch this Promise MongoError?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, mongoose-schema

I upgraded my mongoose, so of course I started getting these:

```
DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library)
is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

so I added `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise`. All good. Except... now I get this guy:

```
(node:20760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: exception: Index with name: stampRoundedToNearestHour_1 already exists with different options
(node:20760) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It's easy enough to fix the underlying error, but I have ***no clue*** where I'm supposed to be catching it so that future versions of Node won't suddenly crash if they encounter similar things. I've produced a minimal version of my code that produces the error. This is one javascript file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

var TestSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  num: Number,
})

TestSchema.index({'num': 1}, { sparse: true })
TestSchema.index({'num': 1}, { sparse: false })
// The above line is deliberately designed to be problematic.
// My question isn't how to not get an error,
// it's that I don't know where to catch it when I do!

// If this line is commented out, there's no error
// but it doesn't return a promise, so I can't .then or .catch on it
var Test = mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema)

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI, {useMongoClient: true})
.then(function () {
  console.log("mongoose.connected successfully")
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log("mongoose.connect catch", err)
})
```

As you can see, I tried both kinds of error handling on the `mongoose.connect()` function, but what is output when I run this is

```
mongoose.connected successfully
(node:26795) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: exception: Index with name: num_1 already exists with different options
(node:26795) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have tried adding `.catch(...)` to literally every other function here:

- `mongoose.Schema(...)`
- `TestSchema.index({'num': 1}, { sparse: true })`
- `mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema)`
- and even `require('mongoose')` (this felt dumb, but I tried it)

...and also to some other functions in my system that I was able to remove while keeping the code broken.

But in all of these cases `TypeError: WHATEVER.catch is not a function`.

Where am I supposed to be catching this `MongoError`? (Again, I know how to prevent it)

Comment: Using `.then(successFunction, errorFunction)` kind of obvites the `.catch()` which is really again just "sugar" for `.then(null,errorFunction)` anyway. Is this ALL the code that is producing the error? You really "should" not be establishing the models "after" actually connecting, but it's not really an error cause. So it's really only the promise chain syntax that I see here. Unless there is other code perhaps?

Comment: Putting that simply. Just try: `mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI, {useMongoClient: true}).then( () => console.log('connected') ).catch( err => console.error(err ) );` for the sake of it, because you appear to have undeclared variables in your existing code that should be throwing the "uncaught exception"

Comment: @NeilLunn yes, I know that. I was just so at a loss because this is literally all the code, so I stuck `.catch()` anywhere that `TypeError` would let me. This is literally one js file, and it creates this error if you run it.

Comment: The "just try" thing totally works fine. Not sure what you mean about undeclared variables. In the existing code, the models are set up before the connection establishes anyway, and I just tried putting the `mongoose.connect(...)` part at the bottom, and it still errors.

Comment: So if your "one js file" has literally "nothing else in it" save for the actual require and `monoogse.Promise = global.Promise` and the line of code I gave you, "what happens then?". Because if there is no error from that ( and there should not be ) then this should illustrate the points of difference. Otherwise you are actually throwing an error in something else you are not showing here. So trying to show you the simple thing to do to fix it. Break down the problem

Comment: Ah, yes, if I remove the `mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema)` then it doesn't error. Should have mentioned that, sorry. But I can't stick a `.then()` or `.catch()` on the end of that, so I'm not sure where I'm supposed to have one that I don't.

Comment: Those functions have nothing to do with promises and are NOT the cause of the error, just like I actually already told you. Your "error" is because you have invalid `err` undeclared variables within statements like `console.log("mongoose.connect reject", err)`. That's the uncaught exception. Already told you that as well.

Comment: Neil, I really appreciate you taking the time to help. I realized that my question was a bit confused because I changed some of the code between copies/pastes from my original file. I have a new example, which addresses what you've said and is still broken. And in case it's not clear, I'm not asking how to stop the exception from occurring, I'm asking how to catch the MongoError.

Comment: Well that's different. The index definitions are the error. But that "is a contrived case" and unless you specifically need to catch that particular error in that case then it's something you can pretty easily avoid by not doing it in the first place. In fact the mongoose documentation recommends you "turn autoindexing off" and do any index creation with "specific code instead". Besides, that's NOT the question you originally posted.

Comment: Ah. It was the question I *thought* I originally posted... sorry if that wasn't clear! In my research before posting I did notice this thing about turning autoindexing off, so I will go and do that.

I was worried that there was a larger (non-contrived) class of non-obvious MongoErrors that were going to screw me up if I switched to global.Promise, so this question represented a test-case for that. But if that's not the case then I guess I'm good!

Comment: If you leave an answer to that effect, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this is due to duplicate indexes being defined.

You should only have one of these lines.

```
TestSchema.index({'num': 1}, { sparse: true })
TestSchema.index({'num': 1}, { sparse: false })
```

The `Unhandled promise` is actually coming from a rejection in [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/834a0e299a518d370e65b2bdb76994e97dbde63f/lib/db.js#L1076) related to `createIndex`.  This is not exposed in mongoose for you to catch errors on.

The likely logical reasoning is simply that you should never have errors in your schema definition.  This is something that could/should be easily caught during development and will not repeat itself later.

Comment: Fixed that (see edited code) and it's still not catching the error. The original syntax was just redundant (because I'm confused af) not actually erroneous, anyway.

Comment: What version of mongoose are you running?

Comment: mongoose@4.12.4

Comment: Yeah, i get the same thing.  In all reality though, your app should never do this.  Since you're defining your schema incorrectly, you would always fix this error before using and it's not something that would ever come up as your app runs.

Comment: I'd also argue that even if you do find a 'solution' to catch it, to add that into your code would be erroneous, as like I say, it's something that should _always_ be fixed before committing/deploying, etc.

Comment: Ha, true! It seems like a bug in mongoose though that this is throwing an error into some promise that can't be caught.

Comment: Yea, just remove your duplicate index on `num`

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a bit more and finding [this article](http://thecodebarbarian.com/unhandled-promise-rejections-in-node.js.html), one possible answer to this question could be adding this line:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(error) {
  // do something with this error
})
```

Doing this means that this warning goes away:

```
(node:26795) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections 
are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled 
will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

But I don't actually know that this would keep the Node.js process from exiting.

Comment: This is not a good idea as it will apply to ALL unhandled rejections in your app.  That's not what you want as in most cases, you want to catch promises, not ignore them.

Comment: Yeah, I basically agree this is a bad idea. I *am* going to use the `process.on('unhandledRejection', ...)` feature to track such unhandledRejections better, eg by printing stacks and maybe also by emailing me if there's an unhandledRejection on production.